# Aws -s3 bucket region issue

Tags: amazon-s3

Created bucket in the region mumbai Asia pac but when accessed with cli - aws configure and region need to be specified as US east 2 instead of mumbai so that i can see the bucket using aws s3 ls cmd. My question why is the bucket not showing up when region given as mumbai? Please let me know thanks.

Comment: The `aws s3 ls` command shows buckets in ALL regions. If you disagree, please edit your question to show how you created the bucket and how you are listing the buckets, and what appears.

Comment: Hi,i did the following . Please see the screen shot and let me know if it s expected behaviour. The bucket created in mumbai but the region you will see in the url is us-east-2. https://www.dropbox.com/s/sdfwgz05lp6r31g/aws_1.JPG?dl=0  
Also, i can access the file using cli as below by providing both the region 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vq15r4kdgr7niqm/aws_2.JPG?dl=0
I thought the bucket can be accessed only by giving the region as mumbai . But is it it correct if its accessible using us-east-2 is what i am confused. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: Is it because buckets are global so its accessible?

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon S3 console (and `aws s3 ls`) shows all global buckets.

Your bucket is shown as Mumbai, but the console (and `aws s3 ls`) is showing ALL buckets, anywhere.

However, if you wish to upload/download to the bucket, you will need to connect to the region where the bucket is located.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CLI configuration needs region name where your S3 bucket has been created, you can find the details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region