# Multiple kafka connects using S3 sink with same `topics.dir`

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I have multiple (independent) kafka clusters, each with `topicA` and `topicB`. Each of these clusters has a kafka-connect running with the S3 sink. Other than the AWS region they're running in, the setup is identical (though they do have different volumes of messages, which isn't relevant here).

Right now, I have `topics.dir` set up as `s3://bucketname/{region}/{connector-name}`. However, I would like that *all* the `topicA` data (from all regions) shares a common prefix and all the `topicB` data (from all regions) shares a different common prefix. I don't actually require that I write to a separate prefix for each region, but I'm assuming having the multiple kafka-connects trying to write to the same place is a recipe for disaster on the off-chance two try to write to the same S3 path.

It occurred to me that I could tweak the `TimeBasedPartitioner` to write to `{region}/yyyy/mm/dd` and change `topics.dir` to be `s3://bucketname/{connector-name}`, so my data would land in `s3://bucketname/{connector-name}/{topic}/{region}/yyyy/mm/dd`. Would this approach work? I don't see why not, though I have yet to try it. (The only obstacle I can imagine is the S3 sink requiring that `topics.dir` not exist when the connector first starts, but that's not documented anywhere, nor is S3 a file system...)

Comment: [S3 buckets are already regional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754094/are-s3-buckets-region-specific), so "region" here refers to the Kafka cluster? Wouldn't this add more cost that writing to a "local" S3 (per region) rather than a single regional bucket?

Comment: `topic.dir` does not need to "exist" since S3 doesn't have "directories", only prefixes. The S3 sink will just write the whole URI as one string.

Comment: Yes `region` refers to the cluster. I'll admit to not having questioned why we write to one bucket rather than one bucket per region (though it is convenient for me that we do). Thank you for the reassurance that it'll work -- S3 may not have directories, but various things sure like to pretend it does.

Comment: You'll need to set `store.url`, I think, or some region config to use a different S3 region. Otherwise, the AWS SDK assumes writing to the region where the connector is running. Running connect sink from a remote region will occur more egress costs than local region consumer. Similarly, writing to non local S3 region would add extra costs, I think

Comment: Confirmed that, as expected, such a partitioning scheme works just fine.